# UITextField becomeFirstResponder triggers _resignFirstResponder

Tags: ios7, uikit, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate, uiresponder

I am programatically creating a `UITextField`, adding it to view and then start editing by calling

```
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

But the issue is this call triggers call to textFieldDidEndEditing: delegate method. The stack trace points to `[textField _resignFirstResponder]` which is invoked by becomeFirstResponder. This is happening on simulator and `iOS 7`. How do I avoid this ? This is causing lot of issues as I don't want `textFieldDidEndEditing:` to be called without keyboard getting dismissed.

EDIT : Here is how I create `UITextField`.

```
    UITextField *titleField = [[[UITextField alloc] init] autorelease];

     [titleField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
     titleField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:0.8];
     titleField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:40.f];
     titleField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
     titleField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
     titleField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    //   titleField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
     titleField.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 80);
     titleField.center = self.previewView.center;
     titleField.delegate = self;


     NSDictionary *titleDictionary = [self titleDictionary];

     if (titleDictionary) {
        titleField.text = [titleDictionary objectForKey:kTitleStringKey];
        NSString *fontName = [titleDictionary objectForKey:kTitleFontNameKey];
        CGFloat fontSize = [[titleDictionary objectForKey:kTitleFontSizeKey] floatValue];
        titleField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize];
        NSData *textColorData = (NSData *)[titleDictionary objectForKey:kTitleTextColorKey];
        titleField.textColor = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:textColorData];

        CGSize size = [titleField.text sizeWithFont:titleField.font];
        titleField.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width + 40, 80);
        titleField.center = self.previewView.center;
     }

     [self.view addSubview:titleField];
     [titleField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Show me the code that, you create UITextField

Comment: Please see the edit in the question. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it. I had a UILongPressGestureRecognizer that triggered adding UITextField routine, and that is incidentally called twice on long press (need to figure out why, but its a separate issue). So becomeFirstResponder was called twice.